R targets: best strategy for branching over larger than memory objects
I have a {targets} pipeline that downloads thousands of weather station data. To do this efficiently I'm using dynamic branching and crew for parallel work, with station-id as the pattern.
Data for each station alone is quite small (10k days). But after I download all data, I need to run an analysis for each. Thus I added a target that uses station-id as the pattern and pass the filtered dataset to the function. This is crashing my machine (I have 32Gb ram). Each worker is consuming large amounts of data, as if each worker is receiving a complete copy of all the weather station.
Is there a way to branch over a large object without having to load it all to memory? I thought about using tar_group but that relies on dplyr::group_by and my entire workflow uses data.table...
Here goes a reprex of what I'm trying to do
library(targets)

tar_script({
  tar_option_set(
    controller = crew::crew_controller_local(workers = 2),
    memory = "transient",
    garbage_collection = TRUE,
    storage = "worker"
  )
  library(crew)
  tar_pipeline(
    tar_target(ids,
               1:100),
    tar_target(station_data,
               data.frame(id = ids,
                          val = runif(1000000)),
               pattern = map(ids)),
    tar_target(corrected_data,
    sort(station_data[station_data$id == ids, 'val']),
    pattern = ids)
  )
  },
  ask = FALSE
)

tar_make()


I suggest that you look up how to use data.table functions with an external database. I'm guessing (without knowing anything about "target pipelines") that you may want your parallelized downloading to push records into the database without going through data.table and then access the database from data.table methods.

Similar, but slightly different is using terra (and can't say if your data will be vector or raster from above);  terra only exposes what is needed for calc in RAM, so in effect a directory (of all files) can serve as database, but the 'only what is needed' may play differently and more conservatively (as to RAM) than a SQL select where call. I'm thinking of getting a 32-64B box, but having to play within 8G pushes looking at other solutions.

Looking here I found a similar problem related to large objects. What Landau suggested was to use format = 'file' in {targets}. That way I could control and load only selected parts of the entire dataset.
To test I rewrote the above reprex using format = file for each target output and my RAM usage is low. So it works!
Bellow is the modified reprex. Beware that this will produce almost 1Gb of files in your disk.
library(targets)

tar_script({
  tar_option_set(
    controller = crew::crew_controller_local(workers = 2),
    memory = "transient",
    garbage_collection = TRUE,
    storage = "worker"
  )
  library(crew)
  tar_pipeline(
    tar_target(ids,
               1:100),
    tar_target(station_data_file,
               {
                 arq <- file.path('data', paste0('input_', ids, '.RDS'))
                 saveRDS(data.frame(id = ids,
                                    val = runif(1000000)), arq)
                 return(arq)
               },
               format = 'file',
               pattern = map(ids)),
    tar_target(corrected_data_file,
               {
                 dt_in <- readRDS(station_data_file)
                 dt_out <- sort(dt_in$val)
                 arq_o <- sub('input', 'output', station_data_file)
                 saveRDS(dt_out, arq_o)
                 return(arq_o)
               },
               format = 'file',
               pattern = map(station_data_file))
  )
},
ask = FALSE
)

tar_make()

